# How secure would it be to choose a random number based on time?

Tags: python, random, cryptography, random-seed

If I had an online room of 10 users arriving at different times and I wanted to pick up a random user once the room is full, would it be secure to select the user by using the timestamp of when the last user joined the room and simply do a % 10 ?

The timestamp would be in milliseconds.

If the answer to my question is no would it be better to add a random delay before selecting the timestamp ?

Comment: I believe applications like encryption that need quality "randomness" often combine multiple sources of entropy. Something like this, involving low bits of a time of a human action can be one kind of source.

Comment: Yes as @aschepler mentioned, If you're doing anything related to security then this might not be the best way to approach this. Time is not random enough for that (result is "pseudo random" number). But if it's for something doesn't require truly random number then yeah time should be okay

Comment: You can use the python libraries to interface with https://qrng.anu.edu.au/ for random numbers, if you really want it to be random

Answer (score 1):

Secure for what? What kind of timestamp, hours?

If timing is used then it is commonly the time source with the best precision, and multiple deltas are used rather than the time stamp directly.

All that is completely inferior to the PRNG's available from a crypto library, fed by the OS random generation. The OS has many more sources for entropy (up to and including the true random generators in many CPU's nowadays).

Just performing mod 10 is kind of dangerous (what if the timer is biased to use even numbers due to lack of precision?), usually we feed *entropy* into a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CS-PRNG).

If those are not fast enough (are they?) and security is not your main need, then you can use a faster non-secure PRNG or a fast stream cipher.